# MySQL replication server as proxy/intermediary?

Tags: mysql, replication

My current infrastructure is composed of a master MySQL server and a number of slaves, all connected via a private network not accessible via Internet.

I need to create another slave located outside the private network, and I'd like to avoid compromising the private network security.

My initial idea is to create another slave, that will be accessible via Internet only to specific IPs (via firewall) to ensure only the specific server can access it, but I was wondering if there was a better alternative that I can implement to let me replicate my master server to an external server.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "better alternative" -- better in what way? What do you think is wrong with the solution you propose?

Comment: why not use a second vpn with another ip range, if you are that concerned, you can use managed switches

Comment: Why do you think access outside the private network compromises network security?

Comment: Thank you for the follow up questions. @mustaccio : I'm not sure my suggested idea is possible. Is it? (create a slave that act as a master for another slave).

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure my hosting provider allows that.

Comment: @danblack I don't want my server to be accessible from outside. It's a production server and I'm pretty sure if I set up a firewall, I'll break things first :p

Comment: @mustaccio Turns out a basic google search yielded the answer for me: https://serverfault.com/questions/145187/can-a-mysql-slave-be-a-master-at-the-same-time. You can answer this, I'll accept your answer :)